# Data repositories for data on the Tumor Microenvironment?

Tags: cancer

Does anyone know of any data repositories for data on the Tumor Microenvironment? I know of the The Cancer Gene Atlas and the Gene Expression Omnibus databases but I'm more curious about data on the (molecular) composition of the TME. (I'm also curious about any databases with data less specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [St Jude Children's Research Hospital](https://www.stjude.org/) Pediatric Cancer data repository [PeCan](https://pecan.stjude.cloud/)?

They have a bunch of data on a wide range of different types of pediatric cancers. These are all in the form of genomes and RNA-seq. However, they also have a bunch of [visualizations](https://viz.stjude.cloud/visualizations) set up so that you can see how these profiles work from a perspective of mutations and RNA in tumours of all sorts.